# Haskell simpleHTTP of Network.HTTP.Conduit performing slowly for get requests

Tags: http, haskell, https, http-conduit, network-conduit

In my haskell code I've imported `Network.HTTP.Conduit` as

```
import Network.HTTP.Conduit
```

In my main function I make a simple `GET` request using `simpleHTTP`

```
main = do
     response <- simpleHttp "https://github.com/trending?l=ruby"
     return ()
```

It took 6 minutes 42 secs to complete 100 api requests

```
time for NUM in `seq 1 1 100`; do ./Testhttp; done
real    6m42.839s
user    0m12.115s
sys 0m2.652s
```

whereas the `ruby` alternative just takes 153 secs for 100 api calls using `Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse("https://github.com/trending?l=ruby"))`

Am I doing something wrong in my haskell code? What are the performant and efficient alternatives to `simpleHTTP`?

Comment: Have you investigated any non language related reasons why this might be? Like difference in user agent or accept encoding for example? Creating a http request is significantly faster in any language then the >1 sec the request takes. As a data point I can mention that when I run your haskell code the result is about the same as your ruby code. When i run the same thing with curl I get twice that.

Comment: I haven't investigated the non language reasons .The Go and the Ruby version take similar amount of time and I expected the Haskell version to also perform similarly but the difference is rather pretty large and I suspect it to be a library issue.

Comment: It does sound like a library issue. Are you running this in a cabal sandbox?

Comment: @TheCriticalImperitive No

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation for `simpleHttp`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.1.5/docs/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html#v:simpleHttp) says:

> Note: This function creates a new Manager. It should be avoided in production code.

Your code creates a new manager for each request. If you change it to reuse a single manager, it could be a lot faster. You can use [`newManager`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.1.5/docs/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html#v:newManager) to create a manager. For example:

```
import Network.HTTP.Conduit
main = do
    request <- parseUrl "https://github.com/trending?l=ruby"
    manager <- newManager conduitManagerSettings
    _response <- httpLbs request manager
    return ()
```

Comment: Of course, running the loop in your shell will still create new managers. You can run the loop in Haskell with [`mapM_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mapM_). Like this: `mapM_ (httpLbs request manager) [1 .. 100]`.

Comment: I repeated the requests to find a better average of the response time for the request. In production I wish to have only one api call and not multiple.

Comment: I think this is the right answer. Just for completeness, I answered this question on Github as well: https://github.com/snoyberg/http-client/issues/118

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that the Haskell library you are using is doing something like an IPv6 DNS request that times out before falling back to IPv4, and Go and Ruby are doing IPv4 requests directly. A few seconds per request is a likely DNS timeout duration and doesn't have any other possible explanation that I can see.